# c# Why can I not return my application from minimize?

Tags: c#, restore, minimize

I have googled this and all the sites I have seen tell me the same thing for minimizing my app and then returning it to normal. I can minimize it fine but when I click on the icon in the tray then nothing happens. Here is my code.

```
private void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool PointerNotOnTaskbar = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Contains(Cursor.Position);
            if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized && PointerNotOnTaskbar)
            {
                notifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Application;
                this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
                notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
                
            }
        }
        private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            notifyIcon1.Visible = false;

            
        }
```

I have also tried

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
```

Comment: If you don't get a StackOverflowException then you probably forgot to subscribe the MouseDoubleClick event.  ShowInTaskbar is a very risky property.  Avoid it by calling Hide() instead, Show() to make the form visible again.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and proved to yourself that notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick() gets called? If yes, can you also ensure it's visible on your desktop? Set position to (0, 0) or whatever works for your setup.

Comment: Are you saying I should use this.Show(); on the mouse click for the icon? I forgot to mention I tried that already also. I don't think the notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick() is getting called at all. I put simple code in there like display a messagebox when double clicked and nothing happens. Its weird I followed a guide on YouTube that did this right in front of me and it worked on his tutorial, but wont work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out this: `this.ShowInTaskbar = false;`
If the form is minimized and not visible in taskbar will take a spell to bring it back!